# Reloading appsettings.json using Strongly type

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

This is my `appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "MySettings": {
    "DefaultSetting": "Key1",
    "Settings": {
      "Key1": {
        "Full": "Description1",
        "Short": "Desc1"
      },
      "Key2": {
        "Full": "Description2",
        "Short": "Desc2"
      },
      "Key3": {
        "Full": "Description3",
        "Short": "Desc3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Class defined:

```cs
public class MySettings
{
  public Dictionary<string, Setting> Settings { get; set; }
  public string DefaultSetting { get; set; }
}
    
public class Setting
{
  public string Full { get; set; }
  public string Short { get; set; }
}
```

My `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // Add framework services.
  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
  services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
  services.AddMvc();
}
```

In HomeController:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  private readonly MySettings _mySettings;
  public HomeController(IOptionsSnapshot<MySettings> mySettings)
  {
    this._mySettings= mySettings.Value;
  }
    
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    return Json(_mySettings.DefaultSetting);
  }
}
```

I want to get the new setting values when I save the changed `appsettings.json` file and refresh my browser.

I have tried the `IOptionsMonitor` before

Here is the [reference](http://andrewlock.net/reloading-strongly-typed-options-when-appsettings-change-in-asp-net-core-rc2/).

But I have many strongly typed classes, it will register too many `IOptionsMonitor`.

Is there an easier way to implement auto reload strongly typed class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reload appsettings on change. To do this, in startup constructor, assign **reloadOnChange** to true like this-

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Comment: my settings in Startup constructor are same with your answer.
But it not work

Comment: As far as i know - `reloadOnChange` is only supported in ASP.NET Core 1.1 and higher.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works after I upgrade the ASP.NET Core